# Objects losing their transformations in scene when re-opening saved file

Tags: transforms, import

A couple of imported objects (.fbx) always return to their original location (center of the scene) as they were imported when saving and re-opening a scene.

I tried to apply transform, scale and orientation using ctrl + A without any result.

What could be the issue? I feel like I'm running out of options here.

Comment: I don't know the issue, but maybe there is a simple workaround. You could create a empty at the middle of the object and parent the object to the empty. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes it should be a possible work around but I do not want to over complicate the scene as it already is pretty complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBX files often come with default pose "animation". Make sure the objects don't have animation keyframes. You can tell if the location boxes in the properties-panel are yellow or green. Also if navigating between frames with left / right arrow keys causes them to reset.

As for workarounds you can make a new mesh object like a cube and navigate to "Mesh" tab and use the mesh dropdown to select the mesh of the imported object. That way you should have a clean, unmodified object using the imported mesh.

Comment: It was indeed the animation that caused the problem I was having.
Used spacebar -> clear animation data to get it resolved.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I often noticed imported fbx were parented to the center. I used to alt + p to unparent them and position them manually, quite time consuming.. Now I avoid them and get objs instead.